# How can I send logs from my functions to user defined file in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

My requirement is I want to redirect all logs related to my module (consisting of functions/triggers) to my own log file. Currently I see it is going under postgres log file (under pg_log folder). Is there a way I can redirect them to user defined file?

P.S: All my functions/triggers are in pl/pgsql.

Comment: you can `copy (select ERROR_MSG) to '/user/path';`